# QuickLook plugin displaying an image and some infos

Tags: objective-c, macos, quicklook

I'm currently writing a QuickLook plugin, and I wondering how I can display an image and some information about that image at the same time, similar to http://www.code-line.com/software/sneakpeekphoto/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one way to do so: Convert your content to an already supported one. This means either PDF or HTML. There are two options you have:

1. For *static information* you create a simple PDF preview by rendering a view into a PDF. (Use `-dataWithPDFInsideRect:` method of `NSView`)
2. For *dynamic information* create a HTML page with links and so on. QuickLook will then show it. (I think this is also the way your example does it.)

We have not found a way to create complex previews on ur own and had to stick to one of the methods, too. Keynote and Pages do the same -- they convert their presentations to multi-page PDF previews...